# Displaying two lists in VF chart

Tags: apex, visualforce-charting

Curently in an apex chart, I am displaying a bar chart . Bar chart data is a List method.

```
public static List<InnerClassName> getMethod1(List<String> Ids)
```

In the VF Page

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.OuterClassName.Method1}', Id, function(result, event) {
```

And in the chart

```
<apex:chart data="JSFunction" height="200" width="90%" background="#FFFFFF" name="NameofMethod">
<apex:legend position="top"/>
<apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" grid="false" fields="NameofMethod" dashSize="2">
```

Question - I want to display two Lists in the same chart . One that is currently getting displayed. Another one with a different filter. 
Since we can give one method name in the chart parameters , 
How to execute this?